# Injecting Entitymanager via XML and not annnotations

Tags: xml, spring, annotations, entitymanager

What I am trying to do is inject through XML almost the same way that is done through A @PersistenceContext annotation.  I am in need of this because of the fact I have different entity managers I need to inject into the same DAO.  The databases mirror one another and I would rather have 1 base class and for instances of that base class then create multiple classes just so I can use the @PersistenceContext annotation.

Here is my example.  This is what I am doing now and it works.

```
public class ItemDaoImpl {
 protected EntityManager entityManager;

 public List<Item> getItems() {
     Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select i from Item i");
  List<Item> s = (List<Item>)query.getResultList();
  return s; 
 }
 public void setEntityManger(EntityManager entityManager) {
  this.entityManager = entityManager;
 }
}

@Repository(value = "itemDaoStore2")
public class ItemDaoImplStore2 extends ItemDaoImpl {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence_unit_2")
 public void setEntityManger(EntityManager entityManager) {
  this.entityManager = entityManager;
 }
}

@Repository(value = "itemDaoStore1")
public class ItemDaoImplStore1 extends ItemDaoImpl {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence_unit_1")
 public void setEntityManger(EntityManager entityManager) {
  this.entityManager = entityManager;
 }
}
```

TransactionManagers, EntityManagers are defined below...

```
<!-- Registers Spring's standard post-processors for annotation-based configuration like @Repository -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- For @Transactional annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"  />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"  />

<!-- This makes Spring perform @PersistenceContext/@PersitenceUnit injection: -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Drives transactions using local JPA APIs -->
<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
 <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
 <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence_unit_1"/>
...
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence_unit_2"/>
...
</bean>
```

What I want to do is to NOT create classes ItemDaoImplStore2 or ItemDaoImplStore1.  I want to have these as instances of ItemDaoImpl via xml instead.  I do not know how to inject the entitymanager properly though.  I want to simulate annotating this as a 'Repository' annotation, and I also want to be able to specify what entityManager to inject by the persistence unit name.  I want something similar to the below using XML instead.

```
 <!-- Somehow annotate this instance as a @Repository annotation -->
 <bean id="itemDaoStore1" class="ItemDaoImpl">
  <!-- Does not work since it is a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
  <!-- Also I would perfer to do it the same way PersistenceContext works
   and only provide the persistence unit name.  I would like to be
   able to specify persistence_unit_1-->
  <property name="entityManager"  ref="entityManagerFactory1"/> 
 </bean>

  <!-- Somehow annotate this instance as a @Repository annotation -->
 <bean id="itemDaoStore2" class="ItemDaoImpl">
  <!-- Does not work since it is a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
  <!-- Also I would perfer to do it the same way PersistenceContext works
   and only provide the persistence unit name.  I would like to be
   able to specify persistence_unit_2-->
  <property name="entityManager"  ref="entityManagerFactory2"/> 
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `SharedEntityManagerBean` - it creates a shared `EntityManager` for `EntityManagerFactory` the same way as `@PersistenceContext`:

```
<bean id="itemDaoStore1" class="ItemDaoImpl"> 
    <property name="entityManager">
        <bean class = "org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name = "entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1"/>  
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide the **persistence unit** name in the xml configuration, using the `SharedEntityManagerBean`, like below:

```
<bean id="testDao" class="com.test.persistence.dao.BaseDAO">
    <property name="entityManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence-test-unit" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*of course, you can have the `SharedEntityManagerBean` as a separate bean*

Here, I m injecting `entityManager` into `BaseDAO` as you're doing using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="...")`