# Inject entity manager from XML in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need to do very similar thing to what is described in [Injecting Entitymanager via XML and not annnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951400/injecting-entitymanager-via-xml-and-not-annnotations), but I need to inject from XML the real, container-created, entity manager, so that it behaves exactly as if there is a real @PersistenceContext annotation. I've found a LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean (notice missing "Container" word), but I'm affraid that it creates a new entity manager factory and therefore entity manager won't be compatible with that injected via real @PersistenceContext annotation.

I will describe the reason, because it is weird and maybe the solution to my problem is to choose completely different approach. I'm using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in my spring configuration and in this configurer I'm referencing other beans. I'm experiencing a bug that autowiring doesn't work in those referenced beans. I don't know why and how PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer turns off autowiring in those referenced beans but the fact is, that if I replace autowiring by xml configuration for those beans, everything works. But I'm unable to replace autowiring of EntityManager, since it's not standard spring bean, but jndi-loaded something I don't fully understand.

One way or the other, is there some solution?

Comment: As far as I understand `EntityManager` created by `SharedEntityManagerBean` from the answer you mentioned behaves exactly as `EntityManager` injected via `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: SharedEntityManagerBean needs entityManagerFactory injected and I don't know what to inject there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="earlyInitializedApplicationSettingsService" class="...services.impl.ApplicationSettingsServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="false">
    <property name="applicationSettingsDao">
        <bean class="....impl.ApplicationSettingsDaoImpl">
            <property name="entityManager">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
                    <property name="entityManagerFactory">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/persistence/somePersistenceUnit"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Notice mainly the fact, that I'm not using standard jee:jndi-lookup, because it didn't work (in the conditions created by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer) and that was the source of my confusion. When I used direct JndiObjectFactoryBean, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in spring-bean.xml ,

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="USER_TEST"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

<bean id="PersonDao" class="com.xxx.java.person.persistence.PersonDAO">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what is described in question that is linked from my question. The problem with this approach is that LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does AFAIK completely custom JPA initialization independent of that in container. I need to have the same infrastructure as is created by container.

Comment: @calavera.info: So, you have a container that creates JPA infrastructure and want to use it, or you want to create "the same infrastructure as is created by container"?

Comment: The first option - I want to use JPA infrastructure created by container. I just don't know how to access it in XML and injection via @PersistenceContext don't work.